# Unity - Sin & Cos circular motion with rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate circular motion (orbit) around an object. The code i have gives me a nice circular orbit around the object. The problem is that when i rotate the object, the orbit behaves as though the object were not rotated.

I've put a really simple diagram below to try and explain it better. The left is what i get when the cylinder is upright, the middle is what i currently get when the object is rotated. The image on the right is what i would like to happen.

[image]

```
float Gx = target.transform.position.x - ((Mathf.Cos(currentTvalue)) * (radius));
float Gz = target.transform.position.z - ((Mathf.Sin(currentTvalue)) * (radius));
float Gy = target.transform.position.y;
Gizmos.color = Color.green;
Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(new Vector3(Gx, Gy, Gz), 0.03f);
```

How can i get the orbit to change with the objects rotation? I have tried multiplying the orbit poisition "new Vector3(Gx,Gy,Gz)" by the rotation of the object:

```
Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(target.transform.rotation*new Vector3(Gx, Gy, Gz), 0.03f);
```

but that didn't seem to do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are calculating the vector (Gx, Gy, Gz) in **world space coordinates**, where the `target` object's rotations are not taken in consideration.

One way to solve your needs is to calculate this rotation using the `target` object's **local space coordinates**, and then convert them to **world space coordinates**. This will correctly make your calculations consider the rotation of the `target` object.

```
float Gx = target.transform.localPosition.x - ((Mathf.Cos(currentTvalue)) * (radius));
float Gz = target.transform.localPosition.z - ((Mathf.Sin(currentTvalue)) * (radius));
float Gy = target.transform.localPosition.y;

Vector3 worldSpacePoint = target.transform.TransformPoint(Gx, Gy, Gz);

Gizmos.color = Color.green;
Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(worldSpacePoint, 0.03f);
```

Notice that instead of `target.transform.position`, which retrieves the **world space coordinates** of the given transform, I am doing the calculations using the `target.transform.localPosition`, which retrieves the **local space coordinates** of the given transform.

Also, I am calling the [TransformPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) method, which converts the coordinates which I have calculated in **local space** to its corresponding values in **world space**.

Then you might safely call the `Gizmos.DrawWireSphere()` method, which requires world space coordinates to work correctly.

Comment: The "TransformPoint" fixes the rotation and works great but it puts the ball quite far away from the virtual object. How can i keep the ball at the same relative position to the object, whilst keeping the rotation (third image).

Comment: never mind i solved my issue, my mistake. I was using the wrong object to transform the point. :)